# Python - Remove quotation marks from list

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with a list of numbers. When printing the list there are quotation marks in the front and at the end which I want to remove.
I'm unable to replace them with the replace function.

```
a = df.iloc[0]['ids']
b = [a]
b (Output) 
['2769734487041924, 7608779650164612'] <-- one quotation mark at beginning and end
```

What I want (created manually):

```
row_ids = [1234, 4567]
row_ids (Output)
[1234, 4567] <-- That's the format I want to get the list to, without the quotation marks
```

Both *b* and *row_ids* data type comes back as 'list' so there must be a way to have the list without the quotation marks.

Comment: iterate over the list element and cast them into int.

Comment: Please check how ids are stored in your data whether in string or int.

Comment: I had the same thought on the data types as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `a` is a string so to get `b` as a list of integers from that you need

```py
b = list(map(int, a.split(",")))
```

Comment: Thanks, 4 hours on google driving me insane, 15mins on here and i got a solution. This works perfectly! For reference the computer format would be b = list(map(int, a.split(',')))

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string and split, Then use base ten to convert it as int.

```
lst = ['2769734487041924, 7608779650164612']
lst2 = []

for i in "".join(lst).split(","):
    lst2.append(int(i, base=10))
print(lst2)
```